# Develop a tool for inserting text/image in a photoshop file

Tags: adobe-photoshop, layers, photoshop-scripting

I'm trying to develop a simple tool for translators who don't have Photoshop but I can't find any library that supports layers.

I need to open the PSD file, translate the text layer and save it as it was. Unfortunately, there is no layer support for the available libraries. So I'm asking for a workaround.

Let's say I get an image from our graphics team that's just a layered background. The translator opens this image with my tool and it renders the text over the image and then save the rendered text as a separate image. I would like to automate the loading process for our graphics team.

Is there an easy way to script (or automate somehow) the following?:

- open the multi-layer image with e.g. button background (without text)
- look for a file (in the same directory) with a certain prefix (like button_en.psd)
- open this prefixed file (with the translated text) and put it over the background image as a top layer

Thanks for the tips

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are essentially looking to do what is called a Data Merge. Photoshop has this facility: see for instance ( http://help.adobe.com/en_US/photoshop/cs/using/WSfd1234e1c4b69f30ea53e41001031ab64-7417a.html#WSfd1234e1c4b69f30ea53e41001031ab64-7414a )